# Image annotation with zooming for large bitmaps

Tags: android, memory, drawing, scale, android-canvas

I am trying to implement an image annotation activity that allows the user to draw on the image as well as pinch to zoom and pan. The image will come from the camera or gallery. I've implemented this by scaling the image down to a manageable size, but I require the image to be at full resolution.

I've seen libraries that tile an image and only display necessary tiles, but these do not allow drawing, or require the image to be in separate row/column jpgs. Neither of which will work for my needs.

Does anyone know a way to implement this, or a library that will work?

Comment: Did you ever end up finding something or creating something for this - I'm in the same boat?